# Save chromomap plots in base R

Tags: html, r

I am using Chromomap in base R in a cluster (not with Rstudio). Could you please tell me if It is possible to save the plots in base R?

I tried with something like this:

```
library(chromoMap)
jpeg("CHR.jpg", width=4000, height= 6000)
chromoMap("chromosome_file.txt","anno.txt", data_based_color_map = T, data_type = "numeric")
dev.off()
```

But didn´t work. I think that chromomap is supposed to produce an HTML in Rstudio. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not possible (same issue here!). I solved using [karyoploteR](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/karyoploteR/inst/doc/karyoploteR.html). I am still working to prettify the output, but I am satisfied, and it allows saving pdf or jpeg of the graph.
Other suggestions are welcome!